# Pretrained model return old output even after adding a new layer

Tags: pytorch

I have a pretrained model that I have used from this repository (https://github.com/ViTAE-Transformer/RSP). The model is ResNet50 with a final FC layer that outputs 51 classes. Since I want to solve my problem which has only 43 classes, I have added another FC layer with an output of 43. I have also frozen the weights of all layers except the last 2 FC layers (The one I added and the one that came with model) to fine tune those 2 layers only. Only issue is when I make the forward pass I end up getting 51 classes which is what the original model predicts instead of 43 (almost as if the last layer was not registed by the model). Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

```
# Load path to RSP Scene Recognition repository in order to load pretrained model
sys.path.append("/home/imantha/workspace/RemSens_SSL/RSP/Scene Recognition")
from models.resnet import resnet50

# Load Model and Pretrained weights
path_to_weights = "pretrain_weights/rsp-aid-resnet-50-e300-ckpt.pth"
res50 = resnet50(num_classes = 51)
res50_state = torch.load(path_to_weights)
res50.load_state_dict(res50_state["model"])

# To Fintune
# Freeze everything !!!
for param in res50.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

# Unfreeze last layer as we want to finetune it too 
res50.fc.weight.requires_grad = True
res50.fc.bias.requires_grad = True

# Add last layer which will also have .requires_grad = True
res50.fc1 = nn.Linear(51, 43)

# some code to get load dataset and data loader
# ...

# Loop through data loader and make forward pass
for X, y in train_loader:
    yhat = res50(X)
    print(f"yhat.shape : {yhat.shape} , y.shape : {y.shape}")
    break

>>> yhat.shape : torch.Size([64, 51]) , y.shape : torch.Size([64, 43])
```

But if you look at all the layers in the model it looks fine,

```
print(res50)

>>>
...
    (2): Bottleneck(
      (conv1): Conv2d(2048, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (conv3): Conv2d(512, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn3): BatchNorm2d(2048, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
  )
  (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(1, 1))
  (fc): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=51, bias=True)
  (fc1): Linear(in_features=51, out_features=43, bias=True)
```

However if I follow this approach it seems to work.

```
new_model = nn.Sequential(
    res50,
    nn.Linear(51,43)
)

for X, y in train_loader:
    yhat = new_model(X)
    print(f"yhat.shape : {yhat.shape} , y.shape : {y.shape}")
    break

>>>
yhat.shape : torch.Size([64, 43]) , y.shape : torch.Size([64, 43])
```

```
print(new_model)
>>>
...
      (2): Bottleneck(
        (conv1): Conv2d(2048, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (conv3): Conv2d(512, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn3): BatchNorm2d(2048, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      )
    )
    (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(1, 1))
    (fc): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=51, bias=True)
  )
  (1): Linear(in_features=51, out_features=43, bias=True)
)
```

Any idea why the previous approach didnt work !

Answer (score 2):

You should read the [basic pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/buildmodel_tutorial.html). You have to change the `forward` method of the model to include the use of `fc1`.

When you run `res50.fc1 = nn.Linear(51, 43)`, all you're doing is assigning `nn.Linear` to the attribute `fc1`. You haven't changed the model. How do you expect the model to know what `fc1` is or when it is supposed to be used?

Although for your case, what you actually want to do is replace `fc` entirely. The `fc` layer predicts classes for the original task the model was trained on. It makes no sense to feed those values into a new layer predicting new classes. You are asking the model to predict your classes by taking a weighted average of the old classes.

You need to replace the `fc` layer entirely and use the model's 2048 size latent representation to predict your output.

In this case you can simply assign `res50.fc = nn.Linear(2048, 43)`. This works (as opposed to the `fc1` case) because the model's `forward` method already uses `fc`.